# Structuring a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm creating a dataframe from an api I'm using. I want to export it as a csv. So far the dataframe structure is:

```
         Lap 1     Lap 2     Lap 3     Lap 4     Lap 5    
driver1  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231
driver2  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231 
driver3  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231
```

The number of laps goes to 64. The number of drivers is 20.
When I export it as a csv and then import it. I get this:

```
    Unnamed:0  Lap 1     Lap 2     Lap 3     Lap 4
0   driver1    1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231
1   driver2    1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231
2   driver3    1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231  1:34.231
```

Just need some help if I'm going in the right direction.

The code I have written so far:

```
def arr_lap_times(driverId):
    # Get JSON from API
    url = 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2020/last/drivers/' + driverId +'/laps.json?limit=63'
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    try:
        # Get maximum of laps the driver did
        lap_num = len(data['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Laps'])
        lap = data['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Laps']
        lap_times = []

        # Adding all lap times into an array
        for laps in range(lap_num):
            # Get time of lap
            timing = lap[laps]['Timings'][0]['time']
            # Convert string into datetime
            # Add lap times into array
            lap_times.append(timing)
        
        return lap_times
    
    except IndexError:     
        #print(driverId + " didn't particpate in this race")
        return []
```

Getting list of drivers from season 2020

```
url = 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2020/drivers.json'
data = requests.get(url).json()

driver_detail = data['MRData']['DriverTable']['Drivers']
num_of_drivers = len(driver_detail)

driverId_arr = []

for driver in range(num_of_drivers):
    driverId_arr.append(driver_detail[driver]['driverId'])
```

Then I put it into a dictionary

```
driver_dict = {}
for driver in driverId_arr:
    lap_times = arr_lap_times(driver)
   driver_dict.update({driver: lap_times})
```

Then I convert the dictionary into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(driver_dict, orient='index')
```

Comment: What you're trying to handle is how `pandas` handles indices when it reads/writes. Could you include the full commands you use to write then read the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

When you read the `.csv' back in as a` DataFrame` simply specify your index column:

```py
file = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', index_col=0)
```

This tells `pandas` that the 0-indexed column in this `.csv` should be treated as the index.